# Getting String response in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var module = (function(){
    return{
        loadJSON: function(url, success, error){
            $.when($.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    format: 'json'
                },
                success: success,
                error: function(err){
                    console.log('Error: ', err);
                }
            })).then(function(data){
                alert('AJAX completed');
            });
        }
    }
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    function _updateCompany(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        data = data.data;
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var item = '<li>Name: ' + data[i]['name'] + ' Total Emp: ' + data[i]['totalCount'] + '</li>';
            $('#companyList').append(item);
        }
    }

    function _error(err){
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    }

    module.loadJSON('/path/to/company.json', _updateCompany, _error);
});
```

Here i get string response and not an object. Hence have to JSON.parse(data);

What is the issue?

Comment: What type of string response are you getting? Are you getting JSON or non JSON string?

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json',` — You are making a GET request, there is no content to describe the type of. Why are you setting this?

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` to the loadJSON function?

Comment: It's probably your web server's fault and it's not returning the response with proper response content type. It might be the client side fault that's not telling the server what should be the proper  response content type. Anyway, the best starting point is looking at Network panel in dev tools and make sure the content type is set to `application/json`

Answer (score 4):

You are getting a plain text response because the server is returning the data with the wrong content-type.

You need the *server* to include `Content-Type: application/json` in the HTTP **response** header for the JSON data.

---

If you set `dataType: "json"` in the options object you pass to `ajax` then you will tell jQuery to ignore the Content-Type and parse it as JSON anyway (but the server is, frankly, misconfigured and you should fix that anyway).

Setting `dataType` will also set the `Accept` request header to tell the server that JSON is prefered … but that is rather implicit in the URL you are giving it.